# I use beamer. I have not a minipage with \footnote at the bottom of a frame

Tags: beamer

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=1610,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{url}
\setsansfont[scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-Text]{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\He}{Lucida Grande}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In .log I receive: LaTeX Warning: Reference footdir@2 on page 6 undefined on input line 112

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I've taken the liberty of reformatting your example.  It's easy to do that -- highlight the code block, then click on the `{}` icon above the window.  Leave a blank line before and after the code block.

Comment: This might in fact be a warning due to something beamer is doing in the background. Maybe try adding some frames and check whether the warning persists